# Why use Static Nested Classes in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I am new to java and have been scratching my head understanding some its concepts.
I am following the tutorial [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). However, I cannot find the usefulness of using Static Nested Classes. I mean I think I need some good examples as to why I should want to use it. Can someone provided me some codes as examples so I can understand it better?
thax

Comment: Please see the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253492/static-nested-class-in-java-why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit of a static nested class over an "ordinary" class is that you can use it to reflect the relationship between two classes.

For example in the JDK there is [`java.util.Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and [`java.util.Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html).

`java.util.Map.Entry` is declared as a `public static interface` and doing it this way clearly signposts its relationship to `Map`.  It could have been defined as `java.util.MapEntry` but doing it as a static nested interface makes it clear that it has a strong relationship to `Map`.

So you'd probably only use static nested class when the nested class would only ever be used in the context of its parent.

Comment: This would certainly be the logical way to program a static nested class but a static nested class doesn't have to know anything about it's parent class.  You could in effect program an outer class called "Zoo" and have a static nested class of "GalacticWarfare" that has nothing to do with the "Zoo" class.

Answer (score 1):

The following example might not be for a Java beginner but one nice example of static nested class is when you want to use the [Builder pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) to construct immutable objects of the outer class. The static nested class is allowed to access private members of the outer class thus constructing objects of the outer class although it has a private constructor and initializing private fields of the outer class.
E.g.

```
    public class SomeClass {
    private int someField;
    private int someOtherField;

    private SomeClass()
    {}

    public static class SomeBuilder {
        private int someField;
        private int someOtherField;

        public SomeBuilder setSomeField(int someField)
        {
            this.someField = someField;
            return this;
        }

        public SomeBuilder setSomeOtherField(int someOtherField) {
            this.someOtherField = someOtherField;
            return this;
        }

        public SomeClass build() throws ValidationException
        {
            validateFields();            

            SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
            someClass.someField = someField;
            someClass.someOtherField = someOtherField;
            return someClass;
        }

        private void validateFields() throws ValidationException {
            //Validate fields
        }
    }

    public int getSomeField() {
        return someField;
    }
    public int getSomeOtherField() {
        return someOtherField;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note - A static nested class doesn't have access to the instance variables and nonstatic methods of the outer class.

Comment: If the nested static class creates objects of outer class then it has access to all private members of the outer class as given in the example.

Comment: Right - I'm just distinguishing the native ability of inner classes from static nested classes.  An inner class actually has a relationship with an outer class and is able to have direct access to outer class members.  A static nested class does not.  In your example, you've created an instance of the outer class in the static nested class.  Otherwise, the static nested class really has no implicit relationship to the outer class.

Answer (score 0):

Nested or inner class is just an ordinary class defined into other class. The reason to do this is typically to hide inner class from others, i.e. it is yet another level of encapsulation.

Inner class can be private, protected and public that mean exactly the same as for fields and methods.

If inner class is not private you  can access it from outside too. Its name is `OuterClass.InnnerClass`. The nesting depth is not limited by Java specification, so inner class can have its own inner classes etc.

If inner class is not static it has yet another feature: ability to call outer's class methods and fields.

Inner class can be also anonymous. This is very useful for small callbacks, event handlers etc.

Hope this helps. Do not hesitate to ask other more concrete questions.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I should add is that if an inner class is *not* static, an instance of it will automatically have a reference to its parent class instance. You can reference it by using: `NameOfOuterClass.this`.

But if it *is* static, then it will not.

This, among other things, comes into play during GC (garbage collection).
Because, if an object of the inner class is not being GCed, then the outer class object it references will not be GCed either (in cases where the inner class was not static).