# what's the static inner class Entry in HashTable used for?

Tags: java, static, hashtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static nested class in Java, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253492/static-nested-class-in-java-why)

I'm reading sourcecode in JDK HashTable, and there is some code snippet like below:

/** Hashtable collision list. */

```
private static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    int hash;
    K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K,V> next;
    ...
} //end of Entry<K,V>
```

I know the Entry here is a private inner class, but it's also a defined static class; 
my concern is, it isn't enough to just define it as private inner class? What's the main usage here to define it as a static class?

Any guide or reply is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you try iterating a `Map.entrySet`, you'll know.

Answer (score 3):

It is `static` so that its instances do not contain a reference to the containing instance of the outer class.

`Map.Entry` is used to iterate through the elements of the map. It is needless for it to have a reference to the containing map, as it needs no access to the private fields of the map. So declaring it non-static would just use up extra space and weaken encapsulation.