# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext()'

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, nullpointerexception, android-context

I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException when I try to get `getApplicationContext()`. I am getting this error from users and not able to reproduce this on my phone.

Could it be that I am calling `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` before the complete Fragment/Activity has been loaded? If that's the problem, what function in the fragment can I be calling the `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` earliest from?

Should I be putting the `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` in `onResume()` that comes last in the lifecycle of the Fragment becoming active?

Basically, I need to call it sometime after the fragment loads.

**onCreateView in my Fragment**:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ctxt = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test,
            container, false);

    //MODE CODE HERE THAT I AM NOT SHOWING  

    //THIS LINE BELOW IS GIVING THE NULL POINTER EXCEPTION - Am I calling getActivity().getApplicationContext() too early in the Fragment's lifecycle?
    _adapter_lv_blockedApps2 = new Adapter_BlockedApps(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(), holder);

    return v;

}
```

Below is the stack trace I am getting from users' phones.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
at com.mavdev.focusoutfacebook.fragments.scheduledblocks.Fragment_scheduled_newdetail$populateLV_blockedAppsFromSystem.doInBackground(Fragment_scheduled_newdetail.java:2597)
at com.mavdev.focusoutfacebook.fragments.scheduledblocks.Fragment_scheduled_newdetail$populateLV_blockedAppsFromSystem.doInBackground(Fragment_scheduled_newdetail.java:2486)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 4 more
```

The complete function:
    private class populateLV_AppsFromSystem extends
            AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            ArrayList<Datamodel> holder = new ArrayList<Datamodel>();

            Map<String, Drawable> map_Apps = new HashMap<String, Drawable>();

            List<String> Apps_List = Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(
                    ToDisplay.getApps(), ","));

            if (Apps_List != null) {
                for (String s : Apps_List) {
                    String s_appName = "";

                    try {
                        s_appName = mAppInfo.getAppNamefromPackage(s,
                                getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        s_appName = "Unknown";
                    }
                    Drawable d = mAppInfo.getIconDrawablefromAppName(
                            s_appName, getActivity());
                    map_Apps.put(s_appName, d); 
                }
            }

            /****************************************************
             * GETTING THE ADAPTER
             ****************************************************/
            for (Map.Entry<String, Drawable> entry : map_Apps
                    .entrySet()) {

                if (isCancelled()) {
                    return null;
                }

            }

            **//THIS IS WHERE THE APP IS CRASHING WITH NULL POINTER**  
            _adapter_lv_Apps2 = new Adapter_Apps(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(), holder);

        } else {
            _adapter_lv_Apps2 = null;
        }

        /****************************************************/

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: not possible, there is no onCreateView in the stacktrace ... and of course getActivity returns null ... from lifecycle of fragment should be obvious when you can use getActivity safety

Comment: Is the line giving a `NullPointerException` part of `doInBackground` method of an `AsyncTask`?

Comment: @TheoK Yes, I tried to remove a bunch of the code to make the question short, but let me add everything.

Comment: more than 2597 lines? are you calling getView on not attached fragment?

Comment: Since you are defining in your fragment a `ctxt = getActivity().getApplicationContext();` try defining it as `final` variable and use that instead of calling it again in the arguments of the `Adapter_BlockedApps`

Comment: @TheoK - Good tip, I will just try that. I could also do a check that if the first time `if(ctxt==null`, just all abort/error on the Fragment and take user back to where they came from with an error message. Thanks.

Comment: @Selvin I am calling the AsyncTask that contains the `getApplicationContext()` from the onCreateView

Comment: You are starting the AsyncTask in onCreateView which ends after fragment is detached

Comment: @Selvin - How can you know that? I am starting the AsyncTask right before onCreateView finishes. Where should I be calling the AsyncTask? in `onResume`?

Comment: IIf you are calling this on a second activity or class, try to call `getApplicationContext()` on the parent activity, send a reference of parent activity, just a suggestion

Comment: I had same issue. But this link helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920942/getting-context-in-asynctask