# How to generate TextView in AsyncTask - PostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to generate a TextView inside AsyncTask's onPostExecute like this :

```
 protected  class AsyncTranslator extends AsyncTask<String, JSONObject, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String mymeaning) {

            TextView myView  = new TextView(this);
            myView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myString));
    }
}
```

But it gives error telling me that this cannot be applied to AsyncTranslator.
Can you tell me how I can generate textViews inside AsyncTask onPostExecute? Thanks.

Comment: How is your Activity supposed to access the TextViews, if they are generated inside the AsyncTask Class?

Comment: I don't use `AsyncTask` much, but have you tried `context` instead of `this`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920942/getting-context-in-asynctask) the possible constructors are

```
TextView(Context context)
TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
```

but you are doing

```
TextView myView  = new TextView(this);
```

inside `AsyncTranslator` which is incorrect.

You can easily create a `TextView` inside your `AsyncTask` if you have a reference to your context. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920942/getting-context-in-asynctask) to get a reference to your context.

**EDIT**
It seems that you already have a reference to your context, so just do

```
TextView myView  = new TextView(context);
```

Comment: Thanks but now it says : **Cannot resolve symbol 'context'**

Comment: But on `onPreExecute()` you do `Toast.makeText(context, "Please wait.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`, so you should know `context`

Comment: Yes but that part is commented out in real code. So there is no context. How can I initialize a context quickly? Thanks.

Comment: I put a link in my answer. See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920942/getting-context-in-asynctask) to get a reference to your context.

Comment: inflate your view inside oncreate of your activity file or you can pass your activity context.

Comment: But I think you do not need to create your `textView` view here, just set the text. Your view must be created in your activity or fragment.

Comment: @Maloubobola I really need to generate textView in there and I couldn't manage to add context in my AsyncTask

Answer (score 1):

In AsyncTask you shouldn't make operations on base UI thread and here you are trying to do it. Try to create new Interface which lets you to pass the result.

```
public interface asyncTaskInterface {
    public void printEditText();
}
```

Then in your AsyncTask:

```
protected  class AsyncTranslator extends AsyncTask<String, JSONObject, String>
{
   public asyncTaskInterface delegate;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    Toast.makeText(context, "Please wait.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String mymeaning) {

        delegate.printEditText();
}
}
```

In your result class you have to implement the interface and pass the class to your async task as delegate:

```
public class myClassActivity implements asyncTaskInterface ...
```

before you will call async task assign the delegate:

```
AsyncTranslator translator = new AsyncTranslator();
translator.delegate = this;
translator.execute();
```

At the end in your activity overwrite the method from your intrface and build in it the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

First create an interface like this:

```
public interface onTextViewCreatedListener {
        public void onTextViewCreated(TextView tv);
    }
```

Then change your AsyncTranslator class like this

```
    protected  class AsyncTranslator extends AsyncTask<String, JSONObject, String>
        {

            private onTextViewCreatedListener onTextViewCreatedListener;

            public AsyncTranslator(onTextViewCreatedListener onTextViewCreatedListener){
                this.onTextViewCreatedListener = onTextViewCreatedListener;
            }


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please wait.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String mymeaning) {

//since you have passed context to Toast in onPreExecute use that context here also.
                TextView myView  = new TextView(context);
                myView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myString));

                if(onTextViewCreatedListener!=null){
                    onTextViewCreatedListener.onTextViewCreated(myView);
                }
            }

        }
```

and then use AsyncTranslator class in your activity class like this:

```
AsyncTranslator asyncTranslator = new AsyncTranslator(new onTextViewCreatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTextViewCreated(TextView tv) {
                //you can use your created textview here
            }
        });
```

that context should be passed from your activity where you are going to call aynctask.execute()