# How to generate a TextView on AsyncTask and place it on a GridLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, textview, grid-layout

This is my situation:
I have a GridLayout (which has some textviews in some cells of it right at the beginning of the activity, but I will change it to generate those textviews dynamically later) and I want to place some textViews in a few cells of it.

The problem: I don't know how many textViews I will need. It depends of the information of the database. Besides, I don't know how to add the textViews generated to the gridLayout from an AsyncTask.

So, I've been looking for some answers but I couldn't make it work. I tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33626172/4129771), but is not exactly what I'm looking for (I create a new TextView, but can't add it to the gridLayout from that thread).
This is the workflow of my app:

1º I start the activity with the gridLayout. It has some textViews:
[image]

This is the main Activity:

```
public class MostrarProyectos extends AppCompatActivity {

private final String TAG = "MostrarProyectos";

//Para obtener de un hilo no principal los proyectos:
public static ArrayList<Proyecto> listaDeProyectos = new ArrayList<>();

public GridLayout grid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar_proyectos);

        grid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);

        EstrategiaObtenerObjetoDB e = FabricaEstrategiaObtenerDB.getInstance().construirEstrategia("proyecto", this); //This is a Fabric, which obtains a Strategy
        e.execute(this.getApplicationContext(), "proyecto", this, this.grid);//I sent a lot of things to test if something gives result
    }
}
```

2º In that main class, I started a new Thread with AsyncTask, to get data from a SQLite DB.
This is the Fabric:

```
public class FabricaEstrategiaObtenerDB {
    private static final FabricaEstrategiaObtenerDB ourInstance = new FabricaEstrategiaObtenerDB();

    public static FabricaEstrategiaObtenerDB getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private FabricaEstrategiaObtenerDB() {}

    public EstrategiaObtenerObjetoDB construirEstrategia(String tabla, Activity acti){
        switch(tabla){
//Some other cases
        case "proyecto":
            EstrategiaObtenerObjetoDBProyecto p = new EstrategiaObtenerObjetoDBProyecto(acti, new onTextViewCreatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTextViewCreated(TextView tv) {
                //I don't know what to do here
                }
            }); //This code I tried from the other stackOverflow answer
            return p;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
}
```

This an abstract class to obtain objects from the DB:

```
public abstract class EstrategiaObtenerObjetoDB extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, ArrayList<Object>> {

protected onTextViewCreatedListener onTextViewCreatedListener; //part of the code from the other StackOverflow user.
Activity miActividad;

public EstrategiaObtenerObjetoDB(Activity act, onTextViewCreatedListener onTextViewCreatedListener){
    this.onTextViewCreatedListener = onTextViewCreatedListener; //This is too code from the other user.
    this.miActividad = act;
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<Object> doInBackground(Object... params) {
    AppDbHelper mDbHelper = new AppDbHelper(miActividad.getApplicationContext()); 
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projection = obtenerSelect();

    Cursor c = armarQuery(db, (String)params[1], projection); //params[1] is the name of the table in the DB
    ArrayList<Object> arrayDeObjetos = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        arrayDeObjetos.add(miActividad.getApplicationContext());//add the context
        arrayDeObjetos.add(miActividad.findViewById(R.id.grid));//add the grid
        armarObjetos(c);
        return arrayDeObjetos;
    }catch (Exception e){
        String b = e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}


@Override
protected abstract void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Object> objects);

protected abstract String[] obtenerSelect();

protected abstract Cursor armarQuery(SQLiteDatabase db, String tabla, String[] projection);

protected abstract void armarObjetos(Cursor c);

}
```

And this is the specific Strategy:

```
public class EstrategiaObtenerObjetoDBProyecto extends EstrategiaObtenerObjetoDB {

public EstrategiaObtenerObjetoDBProyecto(Activity act,onTextViewCreatedListener onTextViewCreatedListener) {
    super(act,onTextViewCreatedListener);
}

@Override
protected String[] obtenerSelect() {
    String[] projection = {
            AppContract.Proyecto._ID,
            AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_NOMBRE,
            AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_DESCRIPCION,
            AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_PRIORIDAD,
            AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_ANIO,
            AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_MES,
            AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_SEMANA,
            AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_DURACION,
    };
    return projection;
}

@Override
protected Cursor armarQuery(SQLiteDatabase db, String tabla, String[] projection) {
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            tabla,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    return cursor;
}

@Override
protected void armarObjetos(Cursor c) {
    c.moveToFirst();

    ArrayList<Object> proyectos = new ArrayList<>();
    do {
        try{
            String nombre = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_NOMBRE));
            String descripcion = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_DESCRIPCION));
            String prioridad = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_PRIORIDAD));
            String anio = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_ANIO));
            String mes = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_MES));
            String semana = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_SEMANA));
            String duracion = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(AppContract.Proyecto.COLUMN_DURACION));
            Proyecto p = new Proyecto(nombre,descripcion, prioridad, anio, mes, semana, duracion);
            MostrarProyectos.listaDeProyectos.add(p);
            proyectos.add(p);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("EstrategiaObtenerPr",e.getMessage());
        }
    } while (c.moveToNext());

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Object> objects) {
    MostrarProyectos.listaDeProyectos.add((Proyecto)objects.get(i));

    GridLayout grid = (GridLayout) miActividad.findViewById(R.id.grid);
    if(!MostrarProyectos.listaDeProyectos.isEmpty()){
        for(int numeroTemporal = 0; numeroTemporal<MostrarProyectos.listaDeProyectos.size();numeroTemporal++){
            Proyecto j = MostrarProyectos.listaDeProyectos.get(numeroTemporal);
            TextView text = new TextView(miActividad.getApplicationContext());
            text.setText(j.getNombre());
            int numFila = MostrarProyectos.contarFilas(j.getMes(), j.getSemana());
            GridLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            params3.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(numFila);//,Integer.parseInt(j.getDuracion())
            Log.d("MostrarProyecto", numFila+","+Integer.parseInt(j.getDuracion()));
            params3.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(3);
            text.setLayoutParams(params3);

            try{
                if(onTextViewCreatedListener!=null){
                   onTextViewCreatedListener.onTextViewCreated(text);//from the other user

                }
            }catch (Exception excepcion){
                Log.d("MostrarProyecto", excepcion.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(miActividad.getApplicationContext(),"No hay proyectos",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    MostrarProyectos.terminoCargaDatos = true;
}
}
```

3º After I get the data, I want to generate as many TextViews as objects I've got from the DB, so I use a 'for' to see how many objects I have inside a temporal list I created. For each object, I want to create a TextView, and add it to the gridLayout (that is on the main thread).

And finally, an interface from the other answer:

```
public interface onTextViewCreatedListener {
    public void onTextViewCreated(TextView tv);
}
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you.

**EDIT_1:** I need to use other thread different from the UI thread because I need to search in the DB the data.

Comment: maybe you can return just the texts from the async task and create the textviews ... or you can use runOnuiThread() method explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850143/android-basics-running-code-in-the-ui-thread

Comment: Just include the list-view -> text-view. Based on the size of the array-list text-view is created dynamically.

Comment: In place of grid view try to use either a recycler view or an expandable list view with adapters.

Comment: @ViperAlpha how can I send anything from an AsyncTask to the main thread? because the main thread won't wait for the other thread to finish.

Comment: @BrunoFernandez you can call RunOnUiThread method from Activity Class, this way, the Android will run it in the Main Thread, see the link I posted. You just need a Context object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your logic, search data in the DB in AsyncTask or simple new Thread() and then create UI elements and attach them in UI thread.

```
mActivity
       .runOnUiThread(
               new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //create a TextView, and add it to the gridLayout
                    }
                });
```