# Passing context from Service to Asynctask without leaking it

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask

I have a `Service` from which I am starting `AsyncTask` from a given timer to do background tasks. My need requires short burst of networking task that's why I am sticking with `Asynctask`.

From `Asynctask` I am doing number of operations(such as launching notifications) that requires `context`. Now, when I am initializing `context` in my `AsyncTask` I am getting a warning "*This fields leaks a context object.*"

I have seen number of questions regarding the same but they all were related to `Activity/Fragment`. So my question is, how can I use `context` in my `AsyncTask`(top level class) **without leaking it**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a Service from which I am starting AsyncTask from a given timer to do background tasks.

Don't use an `AsyncTask`. Use a thread. Or, better yet, used `ScheduledExecutorService` for the timing component, as that will execute tasks on a background thread. `AsyncTask` is *only* appropriate for when you need to do work on the main application thread when the background part is done, and that's rarely required with a service.

Also, bear in mind that your timer will stop working once your process terminates.

> So my question is, how can I use context in my AsyncTask(top level class) without leaking it?

Call `getApplicationContext()` on the `Service` and use that `Context`.

Comment: I am also doing some `Jsoup` calls that's why I heavily rely on `onPostExecute`(to check whether result is null or not). Would calling `getApplicationContext()` will be best practice or holding `weak reference` of `service context`?

Comment: @Michal_196: Parsing HTML has nothing to do with the main application thread; you do not need `onPostExecute()` for parsing HTML. With regards to the `Context`, use `getApplicationContext()`, please. That will return a singleton `Context` (subclass of `Application`), one that initialized as part of starting up your process. That singleton is, in effect, "pre-leaked", and you cannot leak it further by holding a reference to it.

Answer (score 11):

You can pass a [WeakReference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) in your AsyncTask, for example :

```
public class MyAsynctask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

   private WeakReference<Context> mWeakContext;

   public MyAsynctask (WeakReference<Context> reference) {
        mWeakContext = reference;
   }

   // when you need context use mWeakContext.get();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to pass WeakReference from Fragment to AsyncTask

Comment: I got it. `WeakReference weakTextView1 = new WeakReference(textView1);`

Comment: actually I think that's wronog - seems more like this `WeakReference<Context> contextWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);`

Answer (score 10):

You can try using a `WeakReference` and a static inner class for your `AsyncTask` to the object you are trying to access.
Something like this:

```
class MyServiceWhichDoesNotLeak extends Service {

    View view;
    AsyncTask task;

    //Your onCreate and stuff


    private static class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private final WeakReference<View> viewReference;

        public BackgroundTask(View view) {
            this.viewReference = new WeakReference<>(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Background stuff
            return "something";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            View view = viewReference.get();
            if (view != null) {
                //Use your view
            }
        }
    }
}
```