# asynctask not working when app is closed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-recents

I am currently working on a video conferencing app, what I want to achieve is that when someone calls me and upon receiving their call I closed the app by swiping it from recent apps, and then I want to notify the caller by rejecting the call when the app is closed from recent apps

```
public class RecentAppService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "RecentAppStatus";


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand()");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Log.i(TAG, "onTaskRemoved()....!!!!!!!!!!");
    Boolean callactive= AppsharedPreference.getAppPrefrerence(this)
            .readBooleanData("callingactive");
    Log.i(TAG, "onTaskRemoved()....!!!!!!!!!! Callactive ::::"+callactive);

    if(callactive){

        NotificationManager nManager = ((NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));
        nManager.cancelAll();
        rejectCall();

    }


    Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +1000, restartServicePI);


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy()");
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
}

public void rejectCall(){

    AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner(this);
    runner.execute();

}
}
```

I have added the above Sticky service to perform the tasks when someone closes my app from recent apps,i have also added the below code that contains Asynctask to the Service to perform the reject call function

```
class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private String resp;
private Context mcontext;
public AsyncTaskRunner(Context mContext) {
    this.mcontext=mContext;
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    publishProgress("Sleeping..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
    try {

        String mUserHash= AppsharedPreference.getAppPrefrerence(mcontext)
                .readStringData("mUserHash");
        String rejectApi= AppsharedPreference.getAppPrefrerence(mcontext)
                .readStringData("rejectApi");
        String apiToken= AppsharedPreference.getAppPrefrerence(mcontext)
                .readStringData("apiToken");
        String room= AppsharedPreference.getAppPrefrerence(mcontext)
                .readStringData("room");
        String callId= AppsharedPreference.getAppPrefrerence(mcontext)
                .readStringData("callId");

        ApiCallData apiCallData = new ApiCallData(rejectApi, apiToken, room, callId,mUserHash);
        WebService.getWebservice().rejectCall(mcontext, apiCallData, new FutureCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onTaskRemoved()....!!!!!!!!!! Result"+result);

        }
        });
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        resp = e.getMessage();
    }
    return resp;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

Log.i(TAG, "onTaskRemoved()....!!!!!!!!!! Result"+result);
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {


}
}
```

Everything works fine and the call gets disconnected correctly at the callerside when the application is not in foreground but when the app is open,then task is not achieved in Asynctask i.e, Asynctask stops when app is closed.. I am newbie to Android ,Thank you

Comment: you should be using the service context not application context

Comment: Yes you are right i have corrected in my code,but that doesnt solve my problem

Comment: i don't see any code where you are checking the lifecycle of app?

Comment: You should not be using `AsyncTask` with `Service`. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45653186/6383029

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FirebaseJobDispatcher` to perform some action even if app is closed.

to use `FirebaseJobDispatcher` first you need to create a Job , which will be something like this :-

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
                        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                                .setService(SyncJobScheduler.class)
                                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 0))
                                .setTag("Set_your_unique_tag_here")
                                .setReplaceCurrent(false)
                                .build();

                        dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

Put this above code where you want to start any task / perform any specific task

and then you can create your Scheduler class like this :-

```
public class SyncJobScheduler extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters job) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (("Set_your_unique_tag_here").equalsIgnoreCase(job.getTag())) {
                       //PERFORM YOUR TASK HERE_ WHICH YOU WANT TO RUN IN ASYNCTASK OR SERVICE
                        //IT WILL RUN EVEN IF APP IS IN BACKGROUND /CLOSED
                    }
                } catch (Throwable ignored) {

                }
            }
        }).start();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
        return false;
    }
}
```