# AsyncTask : static vs non static nested class vs separate public class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have seen different coding styles when it comes to implementing `AsyncTask` on Android for lightweight background operations. Though I have used static nested class implementation by far, I wanted to understand when and why are these implementations for `AsyncTask` preferred?

1. Static nested class
2. Non-static inner class
3. Separate public class.

I believe the inner classes helps to tightly bound the class to a particular activity/fragment (encapsulation) and also code organization. So, what decides static vs non-static?

With separate classes, though it might be reusable, there's a lot of boiler plate code with use of interfaces to communicate and update the UI elements of fragment/activities. Also, how are each implementations susceptible to memory leaks - for instance when the screen rotates?

> Possible duplicate :
>   [What's the correct way to implement AsyncTask? static or non static nested class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374682/whats-the-correct-way-to-implement-asynctask-static-or-non-static-nested-class)

Comment: *separate private classes* are not possible and all the top-level public classes are, by design, static.

Comment: It depends on what the `AsyncTask` is an inner class of. If the `AsyncTask` is inside an `Activity`, use a `static` inner class. If you use a regular nested class, and a configuration change occurs while the `AsyncTask` is running, now you're in trouble, as the `AsyncTask` is (temporarily) leaking the old `Activity` instance, and if the `AsyncTask` is planning on talking to the `Activity`, it will be talking to the wrong one after a configuration change. Using a `static` inner class avoids the leakage.

Comment: If the `AsyncTask` is inside a retained `Fragment`, a regular nested class is fine. Basically, you are saying that the life of the `AsyncTask` is the same as the life of the `Fragment`. Just be sure to `cancel()` the `AsyncTask` if the fragment is destroyed. If I am going to use an `AsyncTask`, this is my preferred approach, as the task can talk to the fragment (though not the activity) without worrying about configuration changes. If the `AsyncTask` is inside something else, whether it should be `static` or not would depend on what the "something else" is.

Comment: I think you mean static nested class as Java has no concept of static inner class.

Comment: @Blackbelt ahh.yes - separate private classes not possible. About the top-level classes by design being static - could you please elaborate on it wrt to the question?

Comment: @droidx And non-static nested class is known as inner class :). So again no need for writing `non-static inner class`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I liked the suggestion of using a retained fragment. Also, a good pointer there about cancelling the async task on fragment destroy. However, I don't see a good benefit in having separate class files for AsyncTask.