# Can abstract class in Java be static

Tags: java, abstract-class

Why abstract class in Java can't be static ?

```java
static abstract class A {
    abstract void display();
}

class B extends A {
    void display() {
        System.out.println("Inside class A");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A b = new B();
        b.display();
    }
}
```

Above code is giving error: modifier static not allowed here
Tried to understand but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Unmitigated gave you an excellent response below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76069682/421195.  The issue (the source of your compiler error) is that  a static class should be *nested* in another class.  You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16147445/421195 or here: https://www.javatpoint.com/why-we-use-static-class-in-java

Comment: Q: Do you understand what Unmitigated was trying to say?  And why parts of JgWangdu's response was misleading?  The central issue is *YOU CAN'T CREATE A STATIC TOP-LEVEL CLASS*.  For any toplevel class, abstract or not.  EXPLANATION: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7370832/421195,  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1

Answer (score 3):

The `static` modifier would only make sense if the class is defined inside another `class`. `static class` is also illegal in that context; this has nothing to do with it being `abstract`.

All of the following are valid:

```java
abstract class A {}
public class Main {
    static abstract class B {}
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer is there any reason why we can't use static with abstract class.

Comment: @xyzxyz It has nothing to do with the class being abstract. You can't write `static class` there either.