# Compiler errors when static abstract Inner class accesses outer class private fields java

Tags: java, static, compiler-errors, java-7

I have a class with private fieds and also a static abstract inner class with the generic type extending the outer class type, that tries to access the outer class private fields but get's the following error: 
- error: a has private access in Outer
- error: doSomething has private  access in Outer

See code below:

```
public abstract class Outer extends SomeOuter
{
    private Object a;
    private void doSomething(){}

    public static absract class Inner<T extends Outer> extends SomeOuter.SomeInner<T> {     
        public InnerMethod(T p) {
            p.a; //error: a has private access in Outer
            p.doSomething() //error: doSomething has private  access in Outer
        }
    }
}
```

I'm compiling using jdk 1.7

Can anyone please tell me why am getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `Inner class` can access `private field` of enclosing class and a `static inner class`  can also access any private members of enclosing class .

The class itself isn't really "`static`"; there's no such thing as a static class. The
static modifier in this case says that the nested class is a static member of the outer
class. That means it can be accessed, as with other static members, without having
an instance of the outer class.

Since it is a static member , it is able to access outer class's private members , because within class private members are accessible.

eg.

```
class One
{
    private int i=0;
     class Two
    {
         void go()
            {
                System.out.println(new One().i);  //accessible
            }
    }
}
class two 
{
    private  int i=3;
    static class one
    {
        void go()
        {
            System.out.println(new two().i);    //accessible in static class
        }
    }
}
```

But here ,

```
Inner<T extends Outer> extends SomeOuter.SomeInner<T>
```

T is a class which extends Outer , doesn't mean it is inner.
That why it is giving error.

Answer (score 2):

thats how private modifier works if you ever declare any method or variable as private than that things can not be accessed out side the class

Answer (score 2):

A static embedded class is effectively an outer class. It can't access the private members of another class. See the accepted answer to:

[Static nested class in Java, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253492/static-nested-class-in-java-why)

Answer (score 1):

Both the Object and the function you're trying to use are declared as *private*, which means they cannot be used outside the Object. If you want to use them in child classes as well, declare them as *protected*.

Answer (score 1):

Changes the scope of the fields on the `Outer` class to `protected` so that classes extending `Outer` may access these fields.

```
public abstract class Outer extends SomeOuter
{
    protected Object a;
    protected void doSomething(){}


    public static absract class Inner<T extends Outer> extends SomeOuter.SomeInner<T> {     
        public InnerMethod(T p) {
            p.a; //error: a has private access in Outer
            p.doSomething() //error: doSomething has private  access in Outer
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats what you have `private` modifier for. Though it is the inner class, it cannot access the private members of the outer class. So, declare it as `protected`, as you are extending the outer class to inner class