# Why the Entry class in HashMap is static in java

Tags: java, static, hashmap, nested-class

Today when i was seeing the source code of the HashMap class in java i saw that the Entry class in HashMap whcih is used to record the key value pair is static.

```
 static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {

}
```

As far i know that static member of the classes only have one value for all the instances of the class .How this phenomena is applicable in the case of static nested classes.  I also read some discussions in the StackOverFlow can not come to exact point.Below is the link of some explanations that why the Entry class is static.

[Static nested class in Java, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253492/static-nested-class-in-java-why)

Answer (score 2):

> As far i know that static member of the classes only have one value for all the instances of the class.

Correct.

> How this phenomena is applicable in the case of static nested classes?

It isn't. A static nested class doesn't have an implied surrounding object, so it can't access the non-static members of the enclosing class.

The link you posted contains several answers all saying the same as above.

Answer (score 1):

It's really just for organizational purposes.  A static nested class behaves like a top-level class in a package.  In this case, the Entry class is directly related to HashMap so it makes sense to nest it and not pollute the main package.

I would suggest reading up on the Oracle tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html