# Use a non-static method inside a inner class of a static class

Tags: java, oop, static, processing

## Related to

[Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method)

## Context

In Processing, I use the method loadImage() inside a Inner Class. Processing disagrees :

> Cannot make a static reference to a non-static method
>   loadImage(String) from the type PApplet

If I make the main class non-static, then, the error message disappears. I don't understand why my main class can't be static, I don't want to instantiate it because I don't need it.

The inner class is used to create an array of objects.

## Code

```
class PApplet
{
    public loadImage(foo)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

static class MainStaticClass
{
    class InnerClass
    {
        public nonStaticMethod(foo)
        {
            return PApplet.loadImage(foo); // Error 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `nonStaticOtherMethod(foo)` defined? and you may know that `public nonStaticMethod(foo)` is not a valid method signature and you will get errors there too.

Comment: It comes from a another class : PApplet

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question adding the necessary code to reproduce your scenario or we are going just to guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza its better ?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253492/static-nested-class-in-java-why

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza ok that's inner class and not an nested class. corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you posted now is not valid syntax and doesn't really reflect what you're actually doing.

Anyway, the `loadImage()` function is not static, so you can't do this:

```
PApplet.loadImage("img.jpg");
```

And it's also worth noting that every sketch extends the `PApplet` class, so this:

```
PImage img;

void setup(){
  img = loadImage("img.jpg");
}
```

Is converted to Java code that looks like this:

```
public class MySketch extends PApplet{
  PImage img;

  void setup(){
    img = loadImage("img.jpg");
  }
}
```

Here, we can see that the `loadImage()` function is coming from the `PApplet` class, which we're extending.

So now you have something like this:

```
public class MySketch extends PApplet{
  PImage img;

  void setup(){
    img = MyInnerClass.getImage("img.jpg");
  }

  class MyInnerClass{
    public static PImage getImage(String loc){
      return loadImage(loc);
    }

  }
}
```

Or something like this:

```
public class MySketch extends PApplet{
  PImage img;

  void setup(){
    img = new MyInnerClass().getImage("img.jpg");
  }

  static class MyInnerClass{
    public PImage getImage(String loc){
      return loadImage(loc);
    }

  }
}
```

In either case, this will generate an error saying that you can't use the non-static `loadImage()` function from a static context.

That's because the `loadImage()` function is coming from the instance itself. **You need an instance to use a non-static function.** But since the `getImage()` function is static, it doesn't belong to any particular instance. That's why it doesn't work.

If I were you, I would take a step back and ask yourself why you need inner classes at all. If it's a static function, then why not just use a sketch-level function?

Comment: Thank you, I must admit that my question is really bad written, not always easy to figure out what must be added. I solved my problem simply by making my main class non-static and by instantiate it as you recommend. With the  (bad) understanding I've of  OOP , It sometimes hard to distinguish situations where you don't need instance at all than when you need just one. I forgot to mention that all of this class is in a second tab from my processing project, it's not representing a sketch. So all is encapsulated in a main class to make it easier to import in a new project.

Comment: @snoobdogg New tabs are still converted into inner classes, unless the tab ends with `.java`.

Answer (score -1):

Top Level Classes are Static so its redundant and confusing see [Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html) Inner classes are by default non static , you can declare them as Static.
For a non static method you have to instantiate an object of class else things come toppling down - :-)